# Fill elements of a vector randomly depending on constraints

Tags: r, performance, random, vector, indexing

I have a character vector of a certain length (that should not be changed) like this:

```
my.vec <- rep("free", 40000)
```

What I need to do now is the following:

- I need to loop 22 through the vector to represent an annual development (1 loop = 1 year)
- in each loop 7 random elements of the vector should be changed from `"free"` to `"occupied"`
- between two `"occupied"` elements there are supposed to stay at least 4 `"free"` elements (i.e. `"occupied" "free" "free" "free" "free" "occupied"`
- if an element gets assigned `"occupied"` in one loop, is not available anymore for the next loops

For more clarity, here is an example with a short vector and three time steps:

```
# this is the intital vector:
my.vec <- rep("free", 200) 

# this is the assignment in the first three time steps:
# first time step
my.vec[c(1,25,18,10,48,41,33)] <- "occupied"
# second time step
my.vec[c(98,91,81,63,70,163,120)] <- "occupied"
# third time step
my.vec[c(199,127,150,140,172)] <- "occupied"
```

I hope it became clear.
Anybody with an idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
my.vec <- rep("free", 4000)  

# Function to check if a position can be marked 'occupied'
can_occupy <- function(vec, pos) {
  # Check boundaries and ensure at least four 'free' slots between 'occupied'
  if(pos < 1 || pos > length(vec)) {
    return(FALSE)
  }
  lower_bound <- max(1, pos - 4)
  upper_bound <- min(length(vec), pos + 4)
  # If any 'occupied' within bounds, return FALSE
  return(all(vec[lower_bound:upper_bound] == "free"))
}

for(year in 1:22) {
  occupied_this_year <- 0
  attempts <- 0  # To prevent infinite loop in case conditions can't be met
  while(occupied_this_year < 7 && attempts < 1000) {
    # Randomly select a position
    pos <- sample(length(my.vec), 1)
    if(can_occupy(my.vec, pos)) {
      my.vec[pos] <- "occupied"
      occupied_this_year <- occupied_this_year + 1
    }
    attempts <- attempts + 1
  }
  if(attempts == 1000) {
    cat("Year", year, ": Could not occupy 7 positions\n")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this brillant answer @Robert Long. It does exactly what it was intended to do. The answer of zephryl does the same, yet it is less complex, which is why I chose that one.

Answer (score 5):

It will be easier to work with indices, then assign "occupied" into all selected positions at the end. (I used a shorter vector, number of years, and occupations per year for demonstration.)

```r
set.seed(13)
my.vec <- rep("free", 50)

# set params 
years <- 3
occ.per.year <- 2
buffer <- 4

# initialize indices
idx.avail <- seq_along(my.vec)
idx.occ <- integer(years * occ.per.year)

for (i in seq_along(idx.occ)) {
  # pick a new element to occupy
  occ.new <- sample(idx.avail, 1)
  idx.occ[[i]] <- occ.new

  # indices within 4 positions of newly occupied 
  # element are no longer available
  unavail <- seq(occ.new - buffer, occ.new + buffer)
  idx.avail <- setdiff(idx.avail, unavail)
}

my.vec[idx.occ] <- "occupied"
```

Result:

```
 [1] "free"     "free"     "occupied" "free"     "free"     "free"    
 [7] "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"    
[13] "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "occupied" "free"    
[19] "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "occupied"
[25] "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "occupied" "free"    
[31] "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "occupied"
[37] "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "occupied" "free"    
[43] "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"     "free"    
[49] "free"     "free"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot zephryl, your answer is the most straightforward one. While I continued to work on the script, I discoverd that the solution of Robert Long enables to output information at each loop (i.e. timestep or year), which turned out to be needed (e.g., for a graphical representation of annual increase).

Answer (score 3):

## Idea

You actually can solve the problem **from bottom to top**, say, generating indices of "occupied" that are been spaced by `4` "free" at the minimum, and then splitting the indices in to `22` groups (each group has `7` indices).

---

### (Update) If you want higher efficiency, you can try the code below

*Note, the code below is applicable only if `length(my.vec) >= n*iter*4*2`, so length of `40000L` (as shown in the question) works, but `1000L` won't.*

```
my.vec <- rep("free", 40000L)
n <- 7
iter <- 22
r <- 4
i <- seq.int(length(my.vec) %/% r)[c(TRUE,FALSE)]
j <- sample.int(r, floor(length(my.vec) %/% r), replace = TRUE)[c(TRUE,FALSE)]
idx <- sample(r * (i - 1) + j, n * iter)
my.vec[idx] <- "occupied"
out <- asplit(matrix(sample(idx), n), 2) # the 7 random locations in each iteration out of 22 loops
```

and you can check `idx` and the minimum space

```
> idx
  [1]  6384 38031  5471  1861 28275  1532  9313  1013 29922  3374 30144 11562
 [13]  3493 31881 15894 27204 36832 21691 13122 29074 21543 28074  4083 21993
 [25]  7345 11534 10224  9725  6825  2861 26015 37593 34522 35972 34633   181
 [37] 22191  1323 15971  7361 29835 17151 32204 38555 39035 19501  2734 30321
 [49]  8003 11772  4562 12935 33924 10603 39572  8241 25612 18624 10461 10715
 [61] 24603 30765 23895 11201  5204 11523 35794 20792 32173 33684 37825 14683
 [73]  5635 12221 14374 31803   841 11001 33505 30991 24905 29972 24324  7585
 [85]  5964 21305   724 35734 21412  4391 21831 26604 37853 39954  7742  7454
 [97]  9445 10352 33704  4431 32095  9535 31391 29122 33623 37833 14473   995
[109] 29695  4694 38405 37582 33441 12315 19804 39822 29463 27923   782 26105
[121] 18314 30485  1334  7283  5563 20895 32451 11621 21322 38575 22375 28163
[133] 37732 20803 22805  9181 13614 37362 38975 32384 17593 37913 15524 19304
[145] 28295 34285 36305 26701 23964 31925  7055  2824 25675  7595

> min(diff(sort(idx)))
[1] 8
```

---

### (Previous) May be slow due to `repeat`

Below is one example for the implementation

```
my.vec <- rep("free", length = 40000L)
n <- 7
iter <- 22
repeat {
    idx <- sort(sample.int(length(my.vec), iter * n))
    if (min(diff(idx)) >= 5) {
        break
    }
}
my.vec[idx] <- "occupied" # the locations to be assigned with "occupied"
out <- asplit(matrix(sample(idx), n), 2) # the 7 random locations in each iteration out of 22 loops
```

and you will see

```
> out
[[1]]
[1]  9007  4374 24513 29527 12467  5313 26233

[[2]]
[1] 34916 39609 36013 17672 29182 13990 26246

[[3]]
[1]  2510 39439 31930 36786  4060 17269  7720

[[4]]
[1]  9103 31536 20125 38792 31411 39397  6757

[[5]]
[1] 19286 36419 30914 29136 20506 37797 24810

[[6]]
[1] 12310 19571 13024 38857 11752 13587 10396

[[7]]
[1] 17160  7041 24377 10316  4463 17804 30635

[[8]]
[1]  5004 11491 12059 29453 36809 28029  6980

[[9]]
[1]  1393 20848 16932  3605  4716  7290 33564

[[10]]
[1] 27945  7940 27397 26822 37299 38305 32874

[[11]]
[1] 12173 28049 11052 13279 25284 33398 16780

[[12]]
[1] 18873 30753 12535 37830 16603 30601 37961

[[13]]
[1] 20718 20091  5947 31625   442 18258 20608

[[14]]
[1]  8294  8767 23737 31322 10790  1199 24303

[[15]]
[1] 19291 11665  1977 32005 27506 30673 10306

[[16]]
[1] 12296 35511  4912 28066 31344 27769  9814

[[17]]
[1] 18499 23982 12431 18761  4760 38402 33654

[[18]]
[1] 19760 13636 35242  4517 26238  4255  8702

[[19]]
[1] 35408 10257 11234 23589 20941  4295 25686

[[20]]
[1] 15773  7692 33278 19276 37269 38994  6419

[[21]]
[1] 11329 19885 27070 24098 16287  9320 27934

[[22]]
[1] 20590 12378  2722 11280 16282 30431 33363
```

Comment: This may be slow given all the "if" and "break or repeat" steps.  I'll investigate.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes, it might be slow. please see my update, which should be much faster

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding: thanks a lot for your answer and the efforts to update it. It is the most compact solution and also does exactly what I was looking for and moreover it gives you the information which elements where occupied at which time step! That could be very useful in future!

Comment: @climsaver you are welcome, and I guess `out` might be the thing you want to achieve

Comment: I get an error at the line `idx <- sample(5 * (i - 1) + j, n * iter)`   , " Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE' "   .  Maybe check that you have set the correct parameter limits regardless of the length of `my.vec`  ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the prerequisite of the updated approach is that, the length of `my.vec` should be `>= n*iter*10`, so `40000L` (as stated in OP's question) should work, but `1000` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Benchmark test.   I cannot yet test @ThomasIsCoding because his first code runs for more than 20 minutes; the second code throws errors due to choice of `n` and `iter` causing `sample.int` to fail.

```
microbenchmark(zephyr(1000), robert(1000),  times=10)
Year 22 : Could not occupy 7 positions
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 zephyr(1000)  253.667   279.138   316.8863   306.169   325.498   482.268    10  a 
 robert(1000) 7624.805 11681.272 13815.1559 14777.679 15762.078 18064.669    10   b
```

##EDIT:
When I use the specific input length of 40 000, which is necessary for Thomas' second code to execute, I get the following.  Notice that Robert is faster than Zephyr for the larger input.

```
microbenchmark(zephyr(40000), robert(40000), thomas(40000), times=10)
Unit: microseconds
          expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 zephyr(40000) 21790.594 21832.896 23933.1302 22000.891 22861.783 31703.498    10  a 
 robert(40000)  1829.404  1835.685  1858.7584  1858.418  1860.916  1908.292    10   b
 thomas(40000)   796.935   866.973   894.6745   904.547   921.565   953.563    10   b
```

Comment: If you are interested, you can add the recursion version https://stackoverflow.com/a/78049839/12158757 into the benchmark as well :P, but I suspect that it might be slow

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursion that can produce the thing you want

```
my.vec <- rep("free", 40000L)
n <- 7
iter <- 22
p <- seq_along(my.vec)
f <- function(k) {
    if (k == 1) {
        return(sample(p, 1))
    }
    u <- f(k - 1)
    v <- unique(c(outer(u, -4:4, `+`)))
    s <- p[!p %in% v]
    c(u, s[sample.int(length(s), 1)])
}
```

such that

```
> (idx <- f(n * iter))
  [1] 27048 27687 39335 36436  4321 32162  4380  8799 18068 20911 11608  8986
 [13] 35697 31272 32863 33268 37067 16866 29930 35804 24837 15379 38595 22165
 [25] 25207 36356 26572 38299 18473 11674  3604 32621 21753 36750 17731 16021
 [37]  4229 13985 34136 18239 16249 38131 31301 27037 33750 29194 39683 13609
 [49] 35987 24849 29519 13520 12437 22992  8395 19737 27682 38256 17797 25643
 [61] 11458 34991 26271 13558  1455  5834 18277 22201 13901 31184 24433 13839
 [73] 10871 38093 33217 21987 12327 26510 16088 34620 12987 10401   259  2724
 [85]  4298 36712 39567  4688  1355 32410 39357 24745  8024  2275  1548 22932
 [97] 32463  5954 38641    49  6708 16804 29907 16273 33123 22430 14792 33874
[109]  7578 22033 38081 35887 31875 26294 33327 33276 27296 31124 27702 10912
[121] 19959 27341 11001 31381 12339  3892  9565 26714 34908 29765 16389 20901
[133] 13417 18144  3851 38493 15663 17332 18493  8325 14432  2463 13707  2244
[145] 30611 28030 33346 38349 13510 19676 23060 19433 22265 17939

> min(diff(sort(idx)))
[1] 5
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. This also might be of big use.